# Figuring out if haben/sind+partizip II is verb+ adjective or present perfect

Tags: grammar-identification, past

> Die Ende des siebzehnten Jahrhunderts geborenen Brüder Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm sind vielen Deutschen vorwiegend als Verfasser der Märchensammlung "Kinder und Hausmärchen" bekannt.

On first reading, I thought this sentence was present perfect since bekannt is pp II of bekennen [ref](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-german-verb-bekennen.html), but some people on internet told me this is actually a Präsens sentence.

Could someone explain to me how I could've identified that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bekannt* is somewhat a special case*. The problem is that the meaning of *bekennen* and *bekannt* have diverged. While *bekannt* means "known" and is used instead of a passive for *kennen*, *[bekennen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bekennen#German)* means "confess/pledge/plead". *Kennen* itself is almost never used in passive, we say

> Er ist bekannt.

instead of

> (?)Er wird gekannt.

You could only have known if you looked up ["bekannt"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bekannt) itself in a dictionary. Furthermore, since "bekennen" is transitive, its modal verb for perfect would be *haben*, as in

> Er hat seine Schuld bekannt. 
> He has confessed his guilt.

Using *sein* would give the passive, which you might not have learned yet.

*: [*Beliebt*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beliebt#German) (popular) and [*bewusst*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bewusst#German) (concious) work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone explain to me how I could've identified that?

You have to drill for every verb whether its Perfekt auxiliary is *sein* or *haben*. If you ever encounter a *sein* auxiliary in a sentence, you need to recall whether that verb controlled by the *sein* in the sentence has *sein* as a Perfekt auxiliary by dictionary. If not, it's not *Perfekt* tense but rather *Zustandspassiv* voice.

Comment: There are exceptions, but in most cases you can figure out the auxiliary from the meaning; memorizing thousands of verbs is not necessary. The rule of thumb is motion and state change imply "sein" and transitive implies "haben". If in doubt it's probably "haben".